# Is the function $f(x)=x^{2} \chi_{[-1,1] \backslash \mathbb{Q}}(x)$ $\mathcal{L}^{1}$-integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

> Decide whether the function $f:[-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,
> $$
> f(x)=x^{2} \chi_{[-1,1] \backslash \mathbb{Q}}(x)
> $$
> $\mathcal{L}^{1}$-is integrable and, if necessary, calculate the value of the integral of $ f $ over [-1,1] with respect to $\mathcal{L}^{1}$. Justify each step exactly!

**Edit regarding the answer from Mr Gandalf:**

Firstly, the boundedness of the function $f(x)=x^{2} \chi_{[-1,1] \backslash \mathbb{Q}}(x)$:

The function $|f(x)|=\left|x^{2} \chi_{[-1,1] \backslash \mathbb{Q}}(x)\right|=\left|x^{2}\right| \chi_{[-1,1] \backslash \mathbb{Q}}(x)=x^{2} \chi_{[-1,1] \backslash \mathbb{Q}}(x)$ is limited for $x \in$ [-1,1] by $x^{2} \mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]}$, since $x^{2} \mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]}$ in the interval $x \in[-1,1]$ is always greater than or equal to $x^{2} \chi_{[-1,1] \backslash \mathbb{Q}}(x)$.

Now to calculate the measure of [-1,1]:
The Lebesgue measure of $[-1,1]$ is equal to the length of this interval. The interval [-1,1] has a length of 2, which is known from elementary geometry.

Therefore, we have shown that $|f(x)| \leq x^{2} \mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]}$ and $ \lambda([-1,1])=2$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.
Since $\mathrm{Da}|f(x)|$ is bounded and $\lambda([-1,1])$ is finite, we can apply the majorant rule for Lebesgue integrals, which indicates that $f(x)$ is Lebesgue-integrable.

Accordingly, the integral of  f(x)  over [-1,1] with respect to $ \mathcal{L}^{1} $ is equal to the integral of $x^{2}$ over $[-1,1] $, which is $2 / 3$.

Therefore, the function $f(x)=x^{2} \chi_{[-1,1] \backslash \mathbb{Q}}(x)$ is Lebesgue-integrable over $[-1,1]$, and the integral of $f(x)$ over [-1,1] with respect to $\mathcal{L}^{1}$ is $\frac{2}{3}$.

**Is this correct?**

Comment: "Since the function is zero except for irrational numbers, the integral simplifies to $\int_{0}^{1} x^{2}\cdot 0 dx =0$" shows a serious gap in understanding how Lebesgue integral is defined. This being said, no your reasoning is not at all correct.

Comment: Now ask yourself the following questions. What is the measure of irrationals in $[-1,1]$? What about the integral of the function $g(x)=x^{2}$ in $[-1,1]$. How are $f$ and $g$ different? Is $g(x)=f(x)+x^{2}\mathbf{1}_{\Bbb{Q}\cap[-1,1]}$? If yes, then by linearity, isn't $\int g=\int f+\int x^{2}\mathbf{1}_{\Bbb{Q}\cap[-1,1]}$? If yes, then what is $\int_{-1}^{1}x^{2}\mathbf{1}_{\Bbb{Q}\cap[-1,1]}$? Is this an integral over a measure $0$ set? If yes, what is your conclusion?

Comment: bro, $f(x)=x^2\quad a.e.$. two functions with the same value almost everywhere have the same integral, which is a basic conclusion in Lebesgue integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask yourself the following questions:

What is the measure of rationals in $[-1,1]$? Is it a countable set?

What about the integral of the function $g(x)=x^{2}$ in $[-1,1]$ i.e. $g(x)=x^{2}\mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]}$ (You should know this from basic high school calculus)

How are $f$ and $g$ different? Is $g(x)=f(x)+x^{2}\mathbf{1}_{\Bbb{Q}\cap[-1,1]}$?

If yes, then by linearity, isn't $\displaystyle\int_{\Bbb{R}}g(x)\,dx=\int_{\Bbb{R}} f(x)\,dx+\int_{\Bbb{R}} x^{2}\mathbf{1}_{\Bbb{Q}\cap[-1,1]}$?

If yes, then what is $\int_{\Bbb{R}}x^{2}\mathbf{1}_{\Bbb{Q}\cap[-1,1]}\,dx=\int_{\Bbb{Q}\cap[-1,1]}x^{2}\,dx$?

Is this an integral over a measure $0$ set?

If yes, what is your conclusion?

By the way, you did not show integrability. Here is one of the ennumerous ways in which you can do this: $|f(x)|\leq x^{2}\mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]}\leq\mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]}$ and $\int_{\Bbb{R}} \mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]}=\lambda([-1,1])=2$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This task still confuses me a lot and the Lebesgue integral itself too! I have now tried to revise my considerations with your hints and edited my question - is that correct now or am I still doing something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: @Euler007 Yes it's fine now. Just one addition. Integral wrt $L^{1}$ has no meaning as such. We say the $L^{1}$ norm of $f$ is $||f||_{L^{1}}=\int_{\Bbb{R}}|f(x)|\,dx$. And the Integral of $f$ is just $\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x)\,dx$. There's no such thing as an integral wrt to $L^{1}$. Ofcourse $\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x)\,dx =\int_{\Bbb{R}}\max(f,0)-\int_{\Bbb{R}}\max(-f,0)$ and this is how the Lebesgue Integral is defined.